# Mimic C# Actions in Java 8

Tags: java, c#, action, consumer

Actions are nice because you can just pass an arbitrary function returning void as a parameter.

Use cases? Any function wrappers like for example Timers.

So bascially in C# I can write a method

```
private static void Measure(Action block) {
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    block();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

and use it like

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Measure(() => {Console.WriteLine("Hello");});
}
```

to measure the time elapsed for that method. Pretty neat. Now if I want to mimic this in Java I need to write a method

```
private static <T> Consumer<T> measure(Consumer<T> block) {
        return t -> {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            block.accept(t);
            System.out.printf("Time elapsed: %d Milliseconds\n", (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000);
        };
    }
```

and use it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    measure(Void -> System.out.println("Hello")).accept(null);
}
```

**Problems**:

1. Consumers expect only a single argument while Actions can be anything that returns void.
2. Since I can not simply call block() in Java, I need to pass it a redundant `null` parameter.
3. For the latter reason, I have to make measure() itself returning a Consumer.

**Question**:
- Could I mimic this by using a method instead of an external Consumer, thus making the null parameter obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a no-args method, you can use a `Runnable` instead of a `Consumer`.

```
private static Runnable measure(Runnable block) {
    return () -> {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        block.run();
        System.out.printf("Time elapsed: %d Milliseconds\n", (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000);
    };
}
```

And then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    measure(System.out::println("Hello")).run();
}
```

Though, now that I think about it, you don't really need to return the `Runnable`:

```
private static void measure(Runnable block) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        block.run();
        System.out.printf("Time elapsed: %d Milliseconds\n", (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why do you return a runnable? It's not needed as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Yeah, I was half thinking that as well, to be honest.  (I'm just trying to be faithful to the OP's question.)

Comment: Put a simplified version without return. I think this might be what he wants.

Comment: That looks good, however is there any way to do this with variadic functions like in C#?

Comment: The thing is, in C# the `Action` delegate is a no-arg delegate.  You need to add type parameters in order to be able to use arguments.  So the no-arg `Action` is not the same as the single-arg `Action<int>`, for example, which means you'd have to write a different one for each number of arguments.  Similarly in Java, you will need to use the appropriate functional interface for the number of args that you need (`Runnable` for 0, `Consumer` for 1, `BiConsumer` for 2, a custom one for more than that).

Comment: Wait. Every function in Java is Runnable, right? That means I do not have to mess with Consumers at all or create any more methods if I just pass in the arguments, like `measure(() -> add(2,3));`

Comment: That's right. `() -> add(2,3)` is a `Runnable`, as the function itself has no arguments.